# Having trouble with constructors

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

I keep getting errors when I try to build headers, classes and constructors. Dev C++ gives me a bunch of errors, and I don't know how to resolve them. I've included the errors as comments in the code:

Test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header2.h"

int main()
{ //ERROR: new types may not be defined in a return type; extraneous `int' ignored;
  //       `main' must return `int' 
    Object Thing(1);
    std::cout << "The truth value is: " Thing.getValue() << std::flush << "/n";
  //ERROR: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `getValue' with no type 

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Header2.h

```
#ifndef Object_H_
#define Object_H_

class Object
{
 public:
        Object(int a);

        int getValue();
 private:
         int truthValue;
}

#endif // Object_H_
```

Header2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header2.h"

Object::Object(int a)
{ //ERROR: new types may not be defined in a return type; 
  //       return type specification for constructor invalid 
 if (a != 0 || a !=1)
 {
   std::cout << "Improper truth value." << std::flush;
 } else 
 {
  truthValue = a;
  }
}

Object::getValue()
{ //Error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `getValue' with no type 
 return truthValue;
}
```

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `;` at the end of your declaration of `Object`

```
class Object
{
    ....
};
```

Comment: Also he forgot a `<<` between `"The truth value is: " Thing.getValue() `

Comment: @simonc: That helped, but I don't know why. Why do classes need semicolons?

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer (not terribly helpful I'm afraid but) that's what the language standard specifies

Comment: @uk4321: Sigh, I can't believe I didn't noticed that. I added the <<, but now I'm getting linker errors:     [Linker error] undefined reference to `Object::Object(int)' and [Linker error] undefined reference to `Object::getValue()'

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer You need to compile `Object.cpp` as part of the same project as `main.cpp`.  (Or link to a separate library which provides it.)

Comment: @simonc: How do I do that? I thought that having them located in the same folder did that automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I son't know.  I've never used Dev C++.  It should be easy to get instructions by searching for something like "add file to project Dev C++"

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer Just add the file to your project, the IDE should take care of the rest. The reason why you have to have a semicolon after classes is that you can create variable instances between the `}` and the `;`, like `class C { } c1, c2;` or `for (struct { int x = 0, y = 0; } s; s.x < 5; ++s.y) ...` You need the semicolon to tell the compiler that you're not going to declare any variables. **Also** Dev-C++ is extremely old and not worth using; please consider using [the free version of Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2013-express) (Windows Desktop)

Comment: @uk4321: I downloaded Visual C++ like you said and made the changes you recommended. Will try it out. Thanks.